# ServerSocketChannel vs ServerSocket Java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, socketchannel

I have started my work on a pre-developed Java application, where they are dealing with java sockets. The main concept of the project is to get data from the client at the java socket server and process it.

The project has been developed using Java NIO ServerSocketChannel.

Now in this scenario, I could able to get around 70-80 records per second from the client. While if I use simple Java ServerSocket ( Just for testing purpose ) the output zoomed to around 800 reps.

Why is so much difference in both of this?
And how can I modify ServerSocketChannel to imitate ServerSocket?

Here is my main processing part,

```
SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                        if (!key.isReadable()) {
                            key.cancel();
                            client.close();
                            continue;
                        }

                        int[] k = (int[]) key.attachment();

                        if (k[2] == 0) {
                                ByteBuffer lengthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);

                                int bytesRead = -1;
                                if (!client.socket().isClosed() && key.isValid()) {
                                    bytesRead = client.read(lengthBuffer);
                                }

                                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                    key.cancel();
                                    client.close();
                                    continue;
                                }
                                lengthBuffer.flip();
                                byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
                                lengthBuffer.get(bytes, 0, 2);
                                short length = DRMSDecoder.getShort(bytes);


                                k[0]++;
                                k[1] = length;
                                k[2] = 1;
                                key.attach(k);
                                lengthBuffer.clear();
                            } 
                            else {
                                try {

                                    int length = k[1];
                                    ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(length);
                                    dataBuffer.clear();
                                    System.gc();

                                    int bytesRead = -1;
                                    if (!client.socket().isClosed() && key.isValid()) {
                                        bytesRead = client.read(dataBuffer);
                                    }

                                    if (bytesRead == -1) {
                                        key.cancel();
                                        client.close();
                                        continue;
                                    }

                                    dataBuffer.flip();

                                    Hashtable<String, Object> request = decoder.decode(dataBuffer);
                                    short call_type = (Short) request.get("Call Type");

                                    if (request.get("Call Type") != null && (((Short) request.get("Call Type")) == 78 || ((Short) request.get("Call Type")) == 80)) {


                                    } else if (request.get("Call Type") != null && (((Short) request.get("Call Type")) == 79)) {
                                        key.cancel();
                                        client.close();

                                    } 
                                        String message = (String) request.get("Buffer");

                                        handleMessage(message);

                                    }
                                    k[0]++;
                                    k[2] = 0;
                                    key.attach(k);
                                    lastMessageProcessed++;

                                    dataBuffer.clear();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
//                                    System.out.println(e);
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I wrote an article on the fastest to the slowest way I can think of to use IO and NIO in Java. The slowest I could come up with is creating a new connection every time but that was still 3500 messages/s with one client. https://vanilla-java.github.io/2018/08/28/Reducing-network-latency.html I suspect your main delays are not in the network layer. There is a lot you could do to make this code more efficient, but I doubt it explains the slowness you see.  Have you tried to profile your application with JMC?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is **blocking I/O vs non blocking I/O**.

Reference : https://medium.com/coderscorner/tale-of-client-server-and-socket-a6ef54a74763

Comment: but I am already doing this
server.configureBlocking(false);
client.configureBlocking(false);

Comment: Both examples are blocking. NIO's non-blocking is usually a little faster, but in this case, NIO is slower. -1

Comment: @JayVyas NIO is blocking by default.